How can I run additional subroutines after sign in from Clerk authentication in a Next/React/TS application?
A user can either access our Next/React/TS application via a bookmarked link (which could take them to any particular page within the application) or by going to its home page and clicking the Clerk "Sign In" button.  Both of these flows take them to the Clerk sign in page.  After authenticating, they either stay on the home page or are taken to the desired link from the bookmark.  Once the sign in process is complete, before they land at their destination, how can I notify my application that some additional subroutines need to be run to set up some data?  In particular, I need to check if some records exist in my Convex DB and then populate them if they do not exist, but it could be any number of additional things as well.  Because there is no guaranteed page that they will land at after sign in, I need to somehow tie this to the sign in directly.  Thanks for reading!
